# Why does creating a new CloudKit item with viewContext infinitely refresh views?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cloudkit

I am creating an app with the stored data hosted in CloudKit. When I perform a normal swipe to delete action on any of these list items, the `deleteAlert()` displays (as it should). However, as long as the alert is displayed, the code continuously loops and creates an infinite number of blank `Category` values, adding them to the list. At the same time, the alert doesn't allow you to tap on any of the buttons normally, but if you swipe your finger across the button, you can feel lots of short haptic feedback pulses (I suspect it's also looping through creating many overlapping alerts).

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CategoryListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Category.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default)
    private var categories: FetchedResults<Category>
    
    // Passed value
    var accountSelection: String
    
    @State private var deletingItem = false
    @State private var deleteIndexSet: IndexSet?
    @State private var showingAddView = false
        
    var body: some View {
        
        List {

            ForEach(categories) { category in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showingAddView.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("\(category.name ?? "")")
                    }
                }
                    .alert(isPresented: $deletingItem, content: deleteAlert)
            }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    self.deletingItem = true
                    self.deleteIndexSet = indexSet
                }
        }
    }

    func deleteAlert() -> Alert {
        
        var deletedCategory = Category(context: viewContext) // removing this line causes everything to work properly

        try! deletedCategory = categories[deleteIndexSet?.first ?? 0]
        return Alert(
            title:           Text("Delete \(deletedCategory.name ?? "nil")?"),
            message:         Text("Deleting \(deletedCategory.name ?? "nil") will not remove all entries from that category."), // TODO: make it so that if entry does not have a category, add it to a "miscellaneous" or "other" category
            primaryButton:   .cancel(),
            secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {print("")})
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you force-unwrapping deleteIndexSet?

Comment: @ElTomato Because it will always be not nil if it gets to that point, and (I may be mistaken) it should have nothing to do with the issue anyway but idk

Comment: try "attaching" the ".alert(isPresented: $deletingItem, content: deleteAlert)" to the List not the HStack.

Comment: Happened to me before, was because SwiftUI was preloading navigation links. It is definitely because of your alerts.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I actually figured out the answer while I was thinking it over trying to sleep last night :P I'm gonna reword the question and post the answer later today so that if other people are having the same problem, maybe this'll help! (If someone can find the answer before then kudos to you!)

Comment: You aren't show all your cod but you likely have `Category(context: viewContext)` somewhere in your `View`/`body` it is mentioned in some of the SwiftUI documentation that you shouldn't create ManagedObjects/ObservableObjects in a `View`/`body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the view is constantly refreshing boils down to the way `@FetchRequest` works (the array of CloudKit fetched items). Whenever the value of `categories` changes (as with `@State` and `@ObservedObject` etc.), the view it is attached to refreshes. The following loop will repeat endlessly in this case:

1. Inside of `deleteAlert()`, `var deletedCategory = Category(context: viewContext)` creates a new `Category` and immediately adds it to the current context (the list).
2. This causes the view to refresh as previously mentioned.
3. The value of `$deletingItem` is still true, so another alert will display.
4. When an alert is displayed, it triggers the code inside of `deleteAlert()`.
5. Rinse and repeat steps 1-4 infinitely.

TL;DR Don't create `ManagedObjects`/`ObservableObjects` in a `View`/`Body` (as @lorem ipsum also pointed out).